# Find the Ionisation Potential and Electron affinity of X

Tags: periodic-trends, periodic-table, ionization-energy, electron-affinity

$N_0/2$ atoms of $X_{(g)}$ are converted into $\ce{X^+_{(g)}}$ by energy $E_1$. $N_0/2$ atoms of $X_{(g)}$ are converted into $\ce{X^-_{(g)}}$ by energy $E_2$.
Hence ionisation potential and electron affinity of $\ce{X_{(g)}}$ per atom are:

I tried solving this by unitary method, which gave ionisation potential and electron affinity as, ${2E_1/N_0}$, ${2E_2/N_0}$ respectively.

But the answer given is  ${2E_1/N_0}$, ${2(E_2-E_1)/N_0}$

Can anyone please tell me where I went wrong and help me with the solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Ionisation Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy) of an atom is defined as the minimum amount of energy required to remove the most loosely bound electron of an isolated neutral gaseous atom or molecule. In this case, since $E_1$ amount of energy is used to ionise $N_0/2$ atoms, the ionisation energy of each atom is $\frac{E_1}{N_0/2} = \frac{2E_1}{N_0}$.

The [Electron Affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity) is defined as the amount of energy released when an electron is attached to a neutral atom or molecule in the gaseous state to form a negative ion. In this case, $E_2$ amount of energy is released when $N_0/2$ atoms accept electrons to form negative ions, hence electron affinity of each atom is $\frac{E_2}{N_0/2} = \frac{2E_2}{N_0}$.

Your answers are correct. The textbook must have made a typo in the second question. For the textbook's answer to be correct, the second question should read

> $N_0/2$  atoms of $\ce{X+_{(g)}}$ are converted into $\ce{X−_{(g)}}$ by energy $E_2$

This gives the answer as $\frac{E_2 - E_1}{N_0/2} = \frac{2(E_2 - E_1)}{N_0}$ for electron affinity.